# Saving a remote image programmatically with PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, readfile, output-buffering

I am trying to migrate some content from one resources into another and need to save some images (several hundred) located at a remote resource.

Suppose I have only the URL to an image:

```
https://www.example.com/some_image.jpg
```

And I would like to save it into the filesystem using PHP.

If I were uploading the image, I essentially would do the following:

```
<input type="file" name="my_image" />

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_image']['tmp_name'], '/my_img_directory');
```

But since I only have the URL, I would imagine something like:

```
$img = 'https://www.example.com/some_image.jpg';
$file = readfile($img);
move_uploaded_file($file, '/my_img_directory');
```

Which of course wouldnt work since `move_uploaded_file()` doesn't take an output buffer as a first argument.

Essentially, I would need to get `$img` into the `$_FILES[]` array under  this approach. Or may some other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's copy function to copy remote files to a location on your server:

```
copy("https://example.com/some_image.jpg", "/path/to/file.jpg");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://www.url.com/image.jpg');
file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $image); //Where to save the image on your server
```